# CatalogRules: calcProductPriceRule ignores Rule Priority

Tags: catalog-price-rules

The method calcProductPriceRule in Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule can be used to apply product rules on a specific (custom) price. Unfortunately, this method does not apply the rules according to their priority. In my opinion that is because the method getRulesFromProduct() within the corresponding Resource-Model-Class does not add a "order by" condition.

Does anyone know if this is by purpose or just a bug?

PS: We do need to manipulate the price based on complex configuration options - that is why we want to call the calcProductPriceRule-Method.

Answer (score 3):

Guess I solved it by modify

```
public function getRulesFromProduct($date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId)
{
    $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    if (is_string($date)) {
        $date = strtotime($date);
    }
    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->getTable('catalogrule/rule_product'))
        ->where('website_id = ?', $websiteId)
        ->where('customer_group_id = ?', $customerGroupId)
        ->where('product_id = ?', $productId)
        ->where('from_time = 0 or from_time < ?', $date)
        ->where('to_time = 0 or to_time > ?', $date)
        ->order('sort_order');

    return $adapter->fetchAll($select);
}
```

adding ->order('sort_order');